# Does there exist a non-linear surjective function from a lower dimension to a high dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, statistics, linear-transformations, machine-learning

For example, for function F: R2 -> R3. Can the output space of F be R3?

If F is a linear function, the answer is obviously no. But what about non-linear functions? My intuition tells me the answer is no but is there a proof? What about continuous non-linear functions?

Comment: What has this to do `statistics`? Or with `machine-learning`?

Comment: Space filling curves are examples of such functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a space filling curve?
Check out the following link. 
http://people.math.harvard.edu/~kupers/notes/spacefillingfunctions.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there exist bijections between $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}^n$ for any $n$. So, (by composition) there are bijections between $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^m$ for any $n,m$, so in particular for $n=2, m=3$ (and note that bijections in particular are surjections).